# How to send this huge data from client to server after receiving a message from the server

Tags: java, android, tcp

When I tried to send an acknowledgement its receiving (0x06) at server.
public static final byte `ACK[] = {0x06};`

Now I wanted to send this same response after the ACK..

`2303130312C30362C30382C43414E43454C205245515545535445442C32393236323031332C303`

but I am  not able to load like the same, I get an error of OCTAL INTEGER.

```
public static byte RES[] = {2303130312 (from this the error occurs)C30362C30382C43414E43454C205245515545535445442C32393236323031332C303 };
```

Can you pls help me how to send this data from client side to server.

```
while (connected) {
            String receive = TCPClient.byteArrayToHexString(tcpClient.receive(100, 1000));
            String xd = receive.substring( 0,20 );
            Log.d( "WING", xd );
            eReceiveData.setText(xd);
            Log.d( "WINGS SEND", Arrays.toString( TCPClient.StringToByteArray( "0x06" ) ) );
            tcpClient.send(ACK);
```

Comment: There is nothing huge about this data.

Comment: this is the data i need to send "02303130312C30362C30382C43414E43454C205245515545535445442C32393236323031332C3030303030303030303939382C303030322C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C0352"  when i am trying to send them in Bytes the Alphabets in the data are causing the error like octal integer error, int is too long, ..... @user207421

Answer (score 1):

Look at this "[Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)"

You will find how to load your data as byte array.